# Chef Cookbook for Jenkins Amazon EC2 Plugin Configuration

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins

I want to use [Amazon EC2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) for setting up autoscaled Slaves.

We aim to script everything using Chef and so far I haven't found anything for this Jenkins plugin. I want to write a cookbook of my own but am wondering what is the best way to do it?

Comment: http://learn.chef.io

Answer (score 0):

Generally management of the build machine would be done through the EC2 plugin itself, it already installs the Jenkins remote jar for you, so all you need to do beyond that is make sure Java is installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to use Amazon EC2 plugin and Chef together:

1. Run Chef to do provisioning on each slave launch or build start
2. Build pre-baked slave images using Chef and something like [Packer](https://packer.io/) and provide them to Jenkins Amazon EC2 plugin

Cons of the first approach:

- May take a lot of time depending on what software you are installing with Chef. So it would give a latency for build start and extra bill for machine time.
- You can't always get the same build environment you have last time. May lead to heisenbugs and hard troubleshooting.

The second approach is known as [Immutable Server](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ImmutableServer.html). It has its cons too:

- Gives you an extra bill for AMI storage.
- Less flexible — you can't just fix some version numbers or add requirements for some new software and start a new Jenkins build. You have to rebuild your slave images first. And if you need even slightly different environments you have to build and keep several pre-baked images.

I myself use the second approach right now. You could check source code [here](https://github.com/FIDATA/infrastructure/tree/92b40b796203beb1524362e0965ab9af7c0fc703). Specifically, configuration of Amazon EC2 plugin with Chef is done [here](https://github.com/FIDATA/infrastructure/blob/92b40b796203beb1524362e0965ab9af7c0fc703/src/chef/site-cookbooks/fidata-jenkins-master/recipes/default.rb#L531-L630).